# Odbc prepared statement for table with a geometry column type throws exception

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc, prepared-statement

I have a program that runs SQL statements through a MySQL ODBC Connector. When I use a placeholder for a SELECT query on a table that has a geometry column type, an exception is thrown.

This is the code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TestT", connection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE TestT(ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(20), DeliveryLocation geometry DEFAULT NULL)";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestT(ID, NAME) VALUES(1, 'DT'),(2, 'teamDT')";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();


                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TestT where id = ?";

                var parameter = new OdbcParameter("Parameter1", OdbcType.Int);
                parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                parameter.Value = 1;
                command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

                var adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter
                {
                    SelectCommand = command
                };
                var dataSet = new DataSet();

                adapter.Fill(dataSet);
                var table = dataSet.Tables[0];

                Console.WriteLine($"Number of rows returned: {table.Rows.Count}");
            }
        }
        catch (OdbcException exception)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < exception.Errors.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR #" + i + "\n" + "Message: " +
                              exception.Errors[i].Message + "\n" +
                              "Native: " +
                              exception.Errors[i].NativeError.ToString() + "\n" +
                              "Source: " +
                              exception.Errors[i].Source + "\n" +
                              "SQL: " +
                              exception.Errors[i].SQLState + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

Running it as is i get the following output

```
ERROR #0
Message: [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver][mysqld-5.7.23-log]
Native: 517
Source: myodbc5a.dll
SQL: HY000
```

If i change the DeliveryLocation type to int or drop the column from the table, or change the SELECT statement to

```
SELECT * FROM TestT where id = 1
```

I get the following response

```
Number of rows returned: 1
```

How can i prevent the error from happening without having to drop or change the column type and keep the using the placeholder(?) in the SELECT statement?

I'm using the MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver and MySQL 5.7.23

Comment: Are you not able to use the .Net API for MySQL?

Comment: Not in this case, I have to use the ODBC Connector

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I don't think there is support for that data type in odbc. You might consider writing a stored procedure that returns the data you want with the spacial data properties broken out into the things you need in your program.